# C# XML How to serialize a subset of an object and the subset of properties are serialized are driven from a config file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Source code attributes don’t want to be touched cause we have more than one serialization case so I want to make serialization decisions that don’t affect the other processes around me.

The decision to have a config white list is so that updates to what is included in serialization can be a simple config change instead of a code load.

What I have thought of so far is to read in the config that would be a list of parent object names and property name and throw those puppies into a hash table. Loop through all properties of my complex object with `GetProperties()` and check if the name combo I’m currently looking at matches a combo that exists in the hash. If it is a no match then through the xmlIgnore attribute on it via `XmlAttribteOverrides`.

Is there a more effective way of enforcing a serialization white list?

Comment: hi Michael can you provide us more details  by adding your code ?

Comment: Serialization requires a class for each Element except for the leaves that are properties.  When you have set of classes and properties that never change serialization is fine.  If you have a dynamic set of Elements and properties than it is better to use a Net Library like Xml Linq to parse of create an Xml file.

Answer (score 0):

`XmlAttributeOverrides` is something you need to be *really really* careful about - it generates an assemblies every time you `new XmlSerializer` when using it, so you *must* cache and reuse things. Frankly, it may be better to use conditional serialization; i.e. for

```cs
public int Foo {get;set;}
```

you can add a method like:

```cs
public bool ShouldSerializeFoo() {...}
```

which needs to return `true`/`false` depending on whether it should serialize on this occasion.

Comment: I have seen shouldSerializeX in my research. My understanding is that it gets called each time that class is trying to be serialized. What would be the most straight forward condition to check in that function that would allow me to realize I’m in my process path instead of someone else’s? This built in method does not accept arguments right?

Comment: @devaroundtheclock indeed, no arguments; usually you'd do something with your objects to configure which properties should return true/false for this